# How to find out which UILabel from the given set will have the biggest width without constructing them?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

- I am building a `UITableView` that's gonna have have multiple vertical/horizontal rows.
- First horizontal row is going to be headers and the rest - values.
- Since I don't know beforehand the biggest value (length) of the single data item, I cannot predict vertical row's maximum width.
- I'm going to supply minimum widths (equal to the width of `UILabel` that will serve as a title in the first horizontal row) and evaluate the biggest possible value based on the given data set. For that, I have to know, which of the will-be-created labels is going to have the biggest `IntrinsicSize`.

The problem is, I have to know that value **before** I start building my cells, which means I have to create all the labels before I start building, so I'll have to create each label **twice**, once before building the table (to find out if it's gonna be the largest in the vertical row) and once for actually putting it in a custom `UITableViewCell`.

1. Most importantly, **is there a better way to do that?**
2. If no, how to solve the inefficiency of having to create each label twice?

Forgot to mention, everything has to be done from code, since I'm using `Xamarin.iOS` and it has an almost unusable `.xib` editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you can find the ***longest*** string in your dataset, you can use `NSString.GetSizeUsingAttributes` to obtain the height and width based upon the `UIFont` that you will use to render your `UILabel`.

```
var aFont = UIFont.GetPreferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyle.Body);
var attributes = new UIStringAttributes
{
    Font = aFont
};
var rect = (new NSString("The string with the most characters...")).GetSizeUsingAttributes(attributes);
Console.WriteLine($"String width is {rect.Width} when using {aFont.Name}");
```

Add a few pixels to the result if you are adding borders, padding, etc... to your `UILabel`.

Note: As far as what is the longest string in your dataset, I *wing* it and just use the number of characters as the indictor. Yes, using non-proportional fonts could produce a shorter width with a string of more characters compare to another "longer" string, but the alternative is checking the `CGRect` results of every string and that is rarely practical or needed...

Comment: The largest string may not be the one with the most characters. But I can create `NSString`s  for each one of them and compare them, right? Will that be a huge waste, for say, a couple of hundreds of labels?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze Sure you could, but the GC overhead of creating hundreds of `NSString` instances would hardly be worth it.... ***practically*** speaking, grab the string with the most characters and use it as your `UILabel` width....

Comment: another option seems to be, creating all the labels and storing them in the dictionary for the further use. once i create all of them, find the largest one and then use that information when laying them out. i could store these dictionaries in TableSource. what do you think of that?

Comment: i mean, i'll have to create them _anyway_. so why don't simply reuse them?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze Not true, as cell recycling does not require pre-creation of all the elements as cells will be re-used.... In your case, if you are a very small dataset, you can disable recycling but for any dataset that will create more than *one screen* of tables rows, I highly recommend that you do not do that.

Comment: sorry, that won't work. for example, when using `Hind-Regular` with size 15, width of the string `10000` (5 chars) is 37.485 and for `111.11` (6 chars) it is 26.715.

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze Then check the size of every string, not a direction I would go, but if it works for your use-case... or get the max. number of characters and use a "wide" character in the lang' character set, ie.  `new NSString(new String('0', x))`

Comment: just occurred to me :) i can pre-measure all characters and then sum up numbers according to string. i just checked and length of `111.11` is equal to sum of the lengths of `11` and `1.11`.

Comment: since i'm only going to use numbers and several signs, like `'`, `,` and `+`, it's gonna be quite efficient.

Comment: plus i can cache these values and reuse them later, adding new characters if needed to the dictionary.